# What is the usage of IEditableObject with DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, ieditableobject

Here's the excerpt from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vinsibal/5-random-gotchas-with-the-wpf-datagrid:

> 5.Data source items should implement IEditableObject to get transactional editing functionality.
>
> If you are not familiar with IEditableObject, see this MSDN article
> which has a good explanation and code sample.  The DataGrid has baked
> in functionality for transactional editing via the IEditableObject
> interface.  When you begin editing a cell, the DataGrid gets into cell
> editing mode as well as row editing mode.  What this means is that you
> can cancel/commit cells as well as cancel/commit rows.  For example, I
> edit cell 0 and press tab to the next cell.  Cell 0 is committed when
> pressing tab.  I start typing in cell 1 and realize I want to cancel
> the operation.  I press ‘Esc’ which reverts cell 1.  I now realize I
> want to cancel the whole operation so I press ‘Esc’ again and now cell
> 0 is reverted back to its original value.

I get this same transactional behavior even without implementing IEditableObject. What am I missing?

```
  public class Person {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
  }

  People = new List<Person> {
    new Person(){FirstName = "fname", LastName = "lname", Description = "description"}
  };

  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course it doesn't matter that much for a simple string in memory. But there are uses for `IEditableObject`.
For example, imagine you want to store every edited record to a database. You probably would want to commit all changes in one transaction, which would be in `EndEdit()`. Similar uses can be found for the other interface methods.

Also, you are not always directly editing the bound object. Your `IEditableObject` instance might hold a variable of another type wich is the actual data source. You would not apply the edited values until `EndEdit()` was called in that case, and `CancelEdit()` would restore the values from the original data source.

Comment: What if the database operation fails? I don't think EndEdit() is a good place to do a database operation.

Comment: @alice Then you would have to handle the error accordingly. It doesn't have to be a database though, it can also be another in-memory object, or any other object that you don't want anyone to touch until the changes are final. Using a plain object with just a few string properties is not a good example for IEditableObject.

Comment: > "I get this same transactional behavior even without implementing IEditableObject."
How to explain this?Does the DataGrid automatically create an IEditableObject proxy?